# How to display videos with PhotoSwipe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoswipe

Trying to have videos popup and images in photoswipe.. I have images working, but can't figure out how to get videos to work.
I'm guessing that I need to check the data-type, and if it's equal to video it stores the data-video contents, then outputs it in the slider?
I can't get it to work though.

Any help is appreciated

```
<div class="grid popup-gallery">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>  
        <?php if($content_type == 'image') :  ?>
            <div class="grid-item <?php echo $content_size; ?> <?php echo $filter; ?>" data-category="transition" data-index="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <img data-size="<?php echo $image['width']; ?>x<?php echo $image['height']; ?>"  class="full-width" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>">
                <div class="hover-text">
                    <span>VIEW FULL SCREEN</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php else : ?>
            <div class="grid-item <?php echo $content_size; ?> <?php echo $filter; ?>" data-category="transition" data-index="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <a href="#" data-type="video" class="video-link" data-video='<div class="wrapper"><div class="video-wrapper video-position"><iframe class="pswp__video" width="960" height="640" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo $video_link; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>'>
                    <video class="d-block full-width" muted autoplay loop playsinline src="<?php echo $video_thumbnail; ?>"></video>
                    <img class="full-width d-none" src="https://placehold.it/960x500?text=Vimeo">
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
  var items = [];

  function updateItems() {
    items = [];
    $(".popup-gallery").each(function () {
      var $pic = $(this),
        getItems = function () {
          $pic
            .find(".grid-item:not([style*='display: none'])")
            .each(function () {
              if ($(this).data("type") == "video") {
                item = {
                  html: $(this).data("video"),
                };
              } else {
                var $href = $(this).find("img").attr("src"),
                  $size = $(this).find("img").data("size").split("x"),
                  $width = $size[0],
                  $height = $size[1];
                var item = {
                  src: $href,
                  w: $width,
                  h: $height,
                };
              }

              items.push(item);
            });
          return items;
        };

      items = getItems();
    });
  }

  updateItems();

  function openGallery(items, options) {
    var markup = $(".pswp").get(0);
    var gallery = new PhotoSwipe(markup, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
    gallery.init();
  }

  var $index = 0;
  var options = {};
  $(document).on(
    "click",
    ".grid-item:not([style*='display: none'])",
    function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      $index = parseInt($(this).data("index"));
      options = {
        index: $index,
        bgOpacity: 0.7,
        showHideOpacity: true,
        modal: false,
        closeOnScroll: false,
        closeOnVerticalDrag: false,
      };

      options.index = parseInt($(this).data("index"));
      openGallery(items, options);
    }
  );
```

Comment: do you see any errors in console?

Comment: yeah, I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined".. So I'm guessing the if statement is not returning true, so it's not checking the data-video?

Comment: As you can see in this line `$size = $(this).find("img").data("size").split("x"),` the query is trying to find an `img` element but since you have videos, the returned array is undefined (and you cannot call `split()` on it...

Comment: so it's basically not running - if ($(this).data("type") == "video") ?

Comment: it's not entering that part of the if, it seems... you should be able to debug the code to see what type is evaluated at that point (i.e. what is the value of `$(this).data("type")` at that line? (`console.log($(this).data("type"))` should tell you

Comment: could you [edit] your question and add a [mcve] (i.e. rendered html + JS) ? it might make it easier to troubleshoot that way

Comment: It returned undefined. I'll try put something on codepen

Comment: you can also simply use a code snippet here in SO directly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228819/discussion-between-birdyoung-and-blurfus).

Comment: were you able to fix this issue ?